# Last of DIVs that fits the container height

Tags: html, css

I've two (or more) DIVs inside a list item and I'm not able to make the last one to fit the remaining height of its container.

This is the code:

CSS

```
div{margin: 5px;}
ul{
    height: 300px;/*it's calculated via js*/
    width: 250px;/*it's calculated via js*/
    padding: 0;/*don't change it*/
    margin: 0;/*don't change it*/


    background-color: #F5EBD6;
    border: 4px solid orange;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;

    background-color: #E0E5F5;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.item-title{
    background-color: #EDF5E0;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
.item-description{
    background-color: #FDF1FB;
    border: 2px solid fuchsia;
}
.item-description>div{
    background-color:rgba(252,255,170,0.3);
}​
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="item-title">Title</div>
    <div class="item-description">
        <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat 
            nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
            sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat 
            nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
            sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

​

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYFeE/4/).

I'd like that the `.item-description` div (fuchsia bordered div in the Fiddle) will stay inside listItem (the orange bordered element).
The div inside the description, the actual text container, should not be modified in its height.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FAr4C/1/) that shows how it should look like.

### On the right the result I'd like to reach

[image: result]

I'd like to solve the problem using css/css3, not js and without changing the HTML, if possible.

Can you help me?

Comment: Possibly a stupid question but doesn't having a fiddle page showing you how it looks also show you the answer?

Comment: Just from your description, it seems like you are not choosing the correct elements semantically

Comment: @David: now the question seems complete, doesn't it?

Comment: @Ryan: what do you mean?

Comment: I would use a `<dl>` here vs a `<ul>` w/ divs based on the images

Answer (score 0):

Change the `UL` css like below,

```
ul {
    background-color: #F5EBD6;
    border: 4px solid orange;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
}
```

it will works.

Comment: Has I wrote on comment, the ul has an height calculated via javascript and should be that... I can't do without set the height on ul

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

to .item-description

might put all the content inside the div.AM not sure this is what you are expecting

http://jsfiddle.net/Pdaj8/2/

Comment: You modified my second Fiddle, the one with fixed height on .item-description. But it was just to show you what I need, it was an example.

.item-description doesn't have a fixed width

Comment: You mean the height should be dynamically set?

Comment: .item-description class doesn't have a height property and I don't want to set it nneither via css nor via scripting.

Sorry I wrote "width" in the previous comment but I ment "height"